# Как вывести 3 массива в 3 столбца в питоне

Tags: python, python-3.x

как вывести 3 подмассива в 3 столбца, как я понимаю, нужно задать ему координаты х и у

```
table[x][y]
```

что-то на подобе такого, но к сожелению, я никак не могу понять как в питоне их записать (а в гугле я смог найти функции np, но как сделать это без них). Нужно создать дополнительную функцию ?

```
tableData = [['cherries', 'banana', 'apples', 'bobs'],
             ['Alice', 'Carol', 'Bob', 'David'],
             ['dogs', 'cats', 'moose', 'goose']]

def printTable(table):
    for i in table:
        for j in i:
            print(j.rjust(len(max(i)), '+'))

printTable(tableData)
```

благодарен заранее

Comment: а в чем собственно проблема? вроде код тот который нужен

Comment: @alex9127 он выводит все в 1 столб, а мне нужно 3. тоесть table[0][0],  table[0][1], table[0][2],  table[1][0], table[1][1], table[1][2] и так далее

Comment: Ну и в чем проблема-то? Сам же написал нужный код уже.

Comment: @Эникейщик print все в один столб выводит ему 3 надо

Comment: @Эникейщик ну он выводит все 1 столб, а мне нужно 3 столбца

Answer (score 2, accepted):

можно собрать сначала максимальные длины, а потом уже выводить

```
def printTable(table):
    mm = list(map(lambda x: len(max(x, key=lambda y: len(y))), table))
    for i in zip(*table):
        for j in range(len(i)):
            print(i[j].rjust(mm[j], ' '), end='  ')
        print()
```

выведет

```
cherries  Alice   dogs  
  banana  Carol   cats  
  apples    Bob  moose  
    bobs  David  goose
```

Comment: благодарен ))))

Answer (score 1):

Вам нужно использовать аргумент `end` в функции `print()`. По умолчанию этот аргумент равен `\n` (переносу строки). Вы можете изменить этот аргумент с помощью:

```
print(*что-то*, end = " ")
```

Таким образом в конце выведется не перенос строки, а то, чему равен аргумент `end`.

В конце вы просто вызываете пустой print чтобы начать с новой строки, когда вам нужно.

Comment: Спасибо, у меня он вывел все значения в новые столбци, а как задать end, чтобы он выводил целый массив в 1 столбец. я думал end = i или [i] но он не хочет ))

Comment: вот как было у вас без end'а так и нужно. чисто все в один столбец выведет

Answer (score 1):

Может тaк...

```
tableData = [['cherries', 'banana', 'apples', 'bobs'],
             ['Alice', 'Carol', 'Bob', 'David'],
             ['dogs', 'cats', 'moose', 'goose']]


def printTable(table):
    for i in range(min([len(l) for l in table])):
        lst = [el[i] for el in table if len([el]) - 1 <= i]
        print(*lst)


printTable(tableData)
```

Comment: к сожалению он не работает )

Comment: @RostikLugovyy что именно не работает?

Comment: да ничего не выводит, а ошибки нету )

Comment: @RostikLugovyy странно...Вы полностью скопировали мой код и проверили?

Comment: мм, походу баг был, когда в старом окне открываю, не выводит, а если в новом то все ок... сорри

Comment: @RostikLugovyy ну так что, мое решение ответило на ваш вопрос?

Comment: почти )) его еще нужно отцентрировать, спасибо )) с етим я и сам справлюсь))